# Edit post image attributes on fly?

Tags: plugins, customization, filters, actions

Greetings, We can edit image attributes with this get_image_tag filter when we are adding images or with regex and filter the_content,but is there any similar filter or action that can we use to edit these attributes when post is added or edited - updated,and not to write regex?

Here is the link I found.

http://www.webtechwise.com/wordpress-filter-examples-changing-attributes-when-adding-images-to-posts/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do, and why you can't do it with `get_image_tag`?

Comment: get_image_tag works when image is adding to post,I need to change attributes on fly,when post is updated,edited.Any similar action or filter that is fired when post is edited/updated?

Answer (score 1):

When post data is inserted into database it is passed through `wp_insert_post_data` filter in [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function ([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2300)).

According to documentation you can check for set `ID` argument to distinguish posts being updated from posts being created.

Comment: So where I can use wp_insert_post(). Can I use it in my theme metabox.php? or it should be in some particular place?

Comment: @pixelngrain wherever you need to create new post in database?.. Please ask new question if you have specific situation and not sure how to use it.